# OCR: Retrieve essential parts of original image after noise reduction with Python

Tags: python, image-processing, ocr, noise-reduction, scikit-image

I'm trying to denoise an image (photographed text) in order to improve OCR. I'm using Python - skimage for the task, but I'm open to other library recommendations (PIL, cv2, ...)

Example image (should read "i5"):

[image: A noisy i5]

I used `skimage.morphology.erosion` and `skimage.morphology.remove_small_objects` quite successfully, resulting in :

[image: A denoised, badly readable i5]

The noise is gone, but so is some part of the 5 and dot on the i.

**Now the question:** I had an idea how to repair the 5. I add the original image to the denoised one, resulting in parts being black, and parts being gray:

[image]

Then I make all gray parts connected to black parts black (propagate over the structure). Finally, by erasing all parts which are still gray, I get a clean image.

[image]

But I don't know how to do the propagate part using one of the above libraries. Is there an algorithm for that ?

**Bonus question:** How can I preserve the dot on the i ?

Comment: I would do it in a different way: If your "noise" (unwanted information) is similar to the one you show, the easiest way of removing it is by labelling "blobs" in your image, and then just keeping the biggest ones. In order to keep the dot, you could also compute the "with" of each line, by for example computing the morphological skeleton of all your blobs and removing the ones that have very little variation in width from that.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. Identifying all blobs was something I thought about, but you gave me a good idea. The total number of pixels (size) won't be a good indicator for noise, as the diagonals can be long (x-axis). However, I could define something as the maximal height (y-axis), looping over all x-coordinates. All blobs with a max height below x Pixels are noise lines and get eradicated. I try that as an additional step, however I'd still like to have a solution for my initial problem.